# Como hacer un listado de imagenes usando picasso?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, picasso

Estoy tratando de cargar una lista de imagenes que estan en un servidor utilizando picasso.

En el arrayy solo tengo el valor del id de la image:

```
"List<integer> myList = new ArrayList<integer>".
Ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
```

primero intente solo populando el listado usando los valores del id:

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer> 
(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item_title, myList);
            simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

y funciona bien, el listado muestra todos los id.

Pero como puedo hacer esto usando picasso? se que puedo cargar una imagen usando picaso con el siguente formato.

URL = "http://sample.com?id=-aqui va el id que esta en el array-"

Picasso.with(context).load(URL).into(imageView);
pero me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de cargar todas a la vez.

Comment: el valor del id de la imagen que se encuentra en donde Pedro? en el proyecto en  /drawables ?

Comment: @Jorgesys se encuentran en un servidor en internet

Comment: me parece que es mejor idea crear un Adapter personalizado para esto. @Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto te sugiero crear un `Adapter` personalizado, primeramente agrega la dependencia para usar [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/), esto dentro de tu `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    ...
}
```

ahora tu `Adapter` usaría la cadena `"http://sample.com?id="` para completar el url de cada imagen y cargar mediante [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/) la imagen dentro del `ImageView`:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://sample.com?id=" + elements.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);
```

Tu Adapter sería:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adaptercito extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    private final Activity _context;
    private final ArrayList<Integer> elements;

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    public Adaptercito(Activity context, ArrayList<Integer> elements){
        super(context,R.layout.list_item, R.id.item_title , elements);
        this._context = context;
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText("Imagen: "+elements.get(position));

        //* Carga url de imagen en ImageView   
        Picasso.get().load("http://sample.com?id=" +elements.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

el `Adapter` usaría un layout que debe contener un `ImageView` para mostrar la imagen, `list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

De esta forma configura el `Adapter` en tu `ListView`:

```
Adaptercito arrayAdapter = new Adaptercito(this, (ArrayList<Integer>) myList);
simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Para obtener un listado de imágenes similar a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy probando tu codigo y me sale error con el metodo get() a la hora de usar picasso? tienes alguna idea que pueda ser?

Comment: Si utlizo la libreria que me dices de picasso, me da un error el grandle con "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3" me marca error

Comment: Hay que usar las versiones más actuales pero no en extremo (no recomendable usar las alpha),  te sugiero como máximo uses     compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' además targetSdkVersion 27 y cambies esa dependencia  por 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'@Pedro

Comment: Muchas gracias, cambiare las dependencias...para hacer funcionar tu codigo sin cmabiar alguna dependencia solo tube que cambiart el get() a with(_context) y funciono a la perfeccion.

Comment: @Pedro algo importante, la última versión de Picasso ya no usa with(context) , usa únicamente get()  si funciona no hay problema, pero en un futuro si actualizas Picasso, debes realizar este cambio: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Gracias hermano, ya cambie la dependencia y todo funciona bien ! Muchas gracias, ya siento que eres mi profesor de android !

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, aquí hay varios desarrolladores que pueden ayudarte en cualquier caso, solo sigue lo recomendado en [ask],  saludos! @Pedro