# ¿Cómo mostrar eficientemente Bitmaps en un ImageView en Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, bitmap

Actualmente lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathImage));
```

Sin embargo me he encontrado con el siguiente error cuando son imágenes muy pesadas de 3 MB o más.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 63701004 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
```

En un principio este error lo solucioné con colocando esto en el Android Manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Esto sólo me permitió cargar imágenes de aproximadamente 1 MB, ya que sin esto las imágenes debían ser de pocos KB, pero ahora probando la aplicación con imágenes de 3 MB o más me he vuelto a encontrar con el error.

Comment: ¿Imágenes de 3MB? Debe ser al menos una App de super fotografía que muestra imágenes en HD o algo así. Si es el caso, [puedes mirar lo que dice Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) y aplicar un método adecuado. Observa que en la nota (en azul) ellos recomiendan usar [librerías como `Glide`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).  O, considera reducir, optimizar tus imágenes

Comment: La imagen que estas probando ronda 63MB (63.701.004 bytes).

Comment: @Juan, no solamente son dos imágenes de tres mega bytes.

Comment: *Failed to allocate a 63701004 byte allocation* Puede que el archivo sea de 3M pero esta tratando de asignar 63M para el bitmap, por el tamaño y resolución seguramente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad lo que realizaste  puede "ayudar" pero no brinda una solución al problema:

> En un principio este error lo solucioné con colocando esto en el
> Android Manifest:
>
> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
>
> android:largeHeap="true"

**Lo recomendable es optimizar los recursos que usas en tu aplicación**

[Buena resolución de imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror/6359#6359)

Este enlace de la documentación oficial te presenta opciones para realizar la optimización:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer

---

Dos excelentes opciones que pueden ayudar son:

[**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.get()
  .load("http://via.placeholder.com/1000.png")
  .resize(250, 250)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

[Como hacer un listado de imagenes usando picasso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178305/como-hacer-un-listado-de-imagenes-usando-picasso)

[**Glide**](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library)

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load("http://via.placeholder.com/1000.png")
    .override(250, 250)
    .into(imageView);
```

[Problemas al implementar Glide con GridView en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40597/problemas-al-implementar-glide-con-gridview-en-android)