# Api para Imagenes Dinamicas en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me encuentro desarrollando una app en `Android Studio` pero tengo una duda ya que apenas conozco de este tema.

Existe algun `Api` para realizar la carga de imagenes para una App, algo que los usuarios quisieran insertar una imagen desde la galeria y permitiera traer diferentes imagenes no solamente una como si fuesen `ImagesViews` dinamicos como un `gestor de contenido`, existe algo similar para implementrarlo en `Android Studio`?

Comment: Creo que no necesitas una API sino una libreria como Glide que te permite mostrar imagenes desde internet o desde tu dispositivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el mismo SDK, mediante un Intent puedes obtener una imagen de la galería.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona Imágen."), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Al realizar el `Intent` y seleccionar el o las imágenes puedes obtener sus datos mediante la implementación del método `onActivityResult()` y usar [Picasso o Glide](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-eficientemente-bitmaps-en-un-imageview-en-android/221451#221451)  para cargar la imagen en tu `ImageView`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

      if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

        //Carga de imagen seleccionada mediante Picasso. 
       Picasso.get()
       .load(data.getData())
       .centerCrop()
       .into(myImageView);

     }

    }
}
```